# How to create Uboot Initramfs Image for arm64

Tags: linux, arm, initramfs, u-boot

I have initramfs file in gz format (initramfs.cpio.gz). I tried to boot with above gz file, but it shows following error.

*Wrong Ramdisk Image Format
Ramdisk image is corrupt or invalid*

Then i tried to convert the cpio.gz image to uboot supported format by using below command.

*mkimage -n 'Ramdisk Image'  -A arm -O linux -T ramdisk -C gzip -d initramfs.cpio.gz initramfs.uImage*

But there is no support for arm64 in mkimage tool.

Please advice how to create uboot supported arm64 initramfs file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My ARM devices at home do not use initramfs.

Answer (score 2):

After installing the proper uboot tools in host machine, i am able to get the AARCH64 initramfs image successfully.

Cmd:

```
sudo apt-get install u-boot-tools


root@OptiPlex-790:~$ mkimage -A arm64 -O linux -T ramdisk -C gzip -d init.cpio.gz initramfs.uImage
Image Name:   
Created:      Tue Sep 20 18:14:33 2016
Image Type:   AArch64 Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
Data Size:    10240 Bytes = 10.00 kB = 0.01 MB
Load Address: 00000000
Entry Point:  00000000
```

Comment: While correct you may also wish to use either a FIT image or make sure that CONFIG_SUPPORT_RAW_INITRD is set and just pass the location along with your (Linux Kernel generated) Image file to booti.

Comment: I'm asking for clarification on behalf of user @GT with insufficient reputation to post a comment: What version of `u-boot-tools` are you running? I am doing an `apt-get install`, and it is finding version `2013.10-3`. I tried giving it the `-A arm64` flag, and it prints this out : `Invalid CPU Type - valid names are: alpha, arm, x86, ia64, m68k, microblaze, mips, mips64, nios2, powerpc, ppc, s390, sh, sparc, sparc64, blackfin, avr32, nds32, or1k, sandbox`. So what is the "proper" version? Thank you.